# make a dmg package of my node-webkit app

Tags: node-webkit, dmg

I have my node-webkit app running on my mac and I want to make a dmg package to distribute the app.

I have installed the **appdmg** module and is perfect for me.

My json config is this:

```
{
    "title": "myApp",
    "icon": "icon.ico",
    "background": "banner.png",
    "icon-size": 80,
    "contents": [
        { "x": 192, "y": 344, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
        { "x": 448, "y": 344, "type": "file", "path": "../../../deploy/platform/mac/node-webkit.app" }
    ]
}
```

The node-webkit.app is the result of the next command:

```
/Applications/node-webkit.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit myapp
```

I run:

```
sudo appdmg config/platforms/mac/deploy.json deploy/platform/mac/myapp.dmg
```

That build a dmg package with node-webkit but without my app, when I execute myapp it open the node-webkit browser.

I think I missing some configuration in node-webkit.app or something similar, any comment and  approach is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have 1 solution..
I post here to acknowledge :)

You need to put your nw app on

```
/Applications/node-webkit.app/Contents/Resources/
```

The name of your app need to be **app.nw**, is not necessary that you make a zip of your app, can be a folder named app.nw (is faster).